# Selenium Java script Webelement

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use selenium to webscrape the webull screener. However, when I print the xpath to the webelement it just comes up with <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="d9d2a95d8fde18ce1e914b8ca867a370", element="869bb784-0838-498e-8420-f56e67f42e68")>
and if I try executing it with execute_script it says it must be a str.
Here's a copy of my code

```
from selenium import webdriver
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get('https://app.webull.com/screener')
driver.implicitly_wait(15)
peice = 


driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div[3]/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]')
print(driver.execute_script(peice))
```

All I'm trying to do is print the actual symbol in the web screener.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

peice  , contains a webelement object so if you print it you will get object representation printed

use `peice.text` or `peice.get_attribute("textContent")`

this will return the text from the element and prints it.

if you simply pass web element to execute_script you are not executing anything

you should execute something and return something eg:

```
  print(driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].text()" , peice)
```